# Get HTTP requests (performance logs) from chromedriver with protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using protractor for my e2e tests with angular and I'm trying desperately to get HTTP requests logs with headers and body.
I've configured protractor like this:

```
  {

    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,

    maxSessions: 1,
    multiCapabilities: [
        {
            'name': 'desktop',
            'browserName': 'chrome',
            loggingPrefs: {"driver": "ALL", "browser": "ALL", 'performance': 'ALL'},
            chromeOptions: {
                binary: process.env.CHROME_BIN,
                args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox"],
                perfLoggingPrefs: {
                    'traceCategories': 'blink.console,disabled-by-default-devtools.timeline'
                }
            }
        }
    ],

    framework: "custom",
    frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),

    //...
};
```

After each scenario, I'm executing this hook:

```
browser.manage().logs().get("browser").then(logs => 
  //...
)
```

But all I get are console logs but no http requests. Is there any way to get those from chromedriver within protractor?

Here is a link to chromedriver doc mentioning performance logs: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log

Comment: I believe you have to use a proxy, like [browsermob proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)

Comment: The chromedriver documentation tells this:
 ChromeDriver supports performance logging, from which you can get events of domains "Timeline", "Network", and "Page", as well as trace data for specified trace categories.
I've only seen Java examples but no js ones. Is there anyway to make this work with js/ts?

Comment: Oh did not know this, cool.  Glad you found an answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will need to add the following `chromeOptions` including `perfLoggingPrefs` and `loggingPrefs` as shown in https://github.com/angular/protractor-cookbook/blob/master/protractor-javascript/example-network/conf.js

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
      'perfLoggingPrefs': {
        'enableNetwork': true,
        'enablePage': false,
        'enableTimeline': false
      }
    },
    loggingPrefs: {
      performance: 'ALL',
      browser: 'ALL'
    }
  },
```

When getting the logs, the example I wrote has the logging in an `afterEach` method to output after each test.

```
  afterEach(() => {
    browser.manage().logs().get('performance').then((browserLogs) => {
      browserLogs.forEach((browserLog) => {
        var message = JSON.parse(browserLog.message).message;
        if (message.method == 'Network.responseReceived') {
          console.log(message);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

From the logs you should be able to see any get requests made when loading javascript files, assets, etc.

#### Updated answer

Updating answer per comment. If you use `'Network.requestWillBeSent'`, you can view POSTs.

Comment: Thank you !! Also, if you want to get params of a post request, you can filter by method: 'Network.requestWillBeSent' and you get them in postData array :)

Comment: `chromeOptions` now is `goog:chromeOptions`

Comment: Multiple people have updated that. It must be a thing. This should probably be updated in Protractor's documentation.

Comment: How to get response body?

Comment: I found that you also need to add `w3c: false,` inside of the `chromeOptions ` to make performance work.