# Get HTTP requests (performance logs) from IE with protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, internet-explorer-11, browserstack

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114793/get-http-requests-performance-logs-from-chromedriver-with-protractor/49123392#49123392?newreg=4cd7cfbc57f949d288f50699b56cf520) works in Chrome, but in IE I keep facing this error:

```js
Message:
Failed: Command not found: POST /session/798d3aecb62d1bbb9e31c521af84b9182eed519f/log
Stack:
WebDriverError: Command not found: POST /session/798d3aecb62d1bbb9e31c521af84b9182eed519f/log
  at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/Users/agupta7/Documents/data-surveyor-client-side/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:542:13)
  at parseHttpResponse (/Users/agupta7/Documents/data-surveyor-client-side/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
  at /Users/agupta7/Documents/data-surveyor-client-side/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().logs().get(performance)
```

Any solution to fetch the network logs in IE11 browser with protractor (I am using it with BrowserStack)?

Comment: What version of Protractor and Selenium Webdriver are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the [ChromeDriver supports performance logging](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging/performance-log), but IE WebDriver doesn't support the logging APIs, and doesn't support getting logs of any kind. Because, the IE driver implements the [W3C WebDriver Specification](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/), which does not supply any log retrieval end points at all. Moreover, even if the driver were to implement the logging API, getting the console log in IE would still be impossible, since Internet Explorer does not provide any programmatic access to its debugging tools.

Here are some similar threads, you could check them:

[InternetExplorerDriver can't retrieve browser logs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6414)

[Unable to get browser logs from IE and chrome](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2602)

Besides, since the IE driver is available on GitHub, and pull requests implementing new features are accepted. You could try to feedback this request on [IE Driver Github forum](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver).

Answer (score 0):

IE driver does not support getting logs. However, network logs can be generated via an MiTM proxy.

BrowserStack does the exact same thing with the network logs capability.

```
"browserstack.networkLogs": "true"
```

This works for IE 11 on Windows 10 as mentioned here: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities

In the case of your protractor test, you need to add the above capability in your configuration.

The logs appear on the dashboard.

Comment: yes, that works but I need to get these logs programatically and then validate some of the requests.