# How to get headers in protractor E2E

Tags: javascript, protractor, e2e-testing

Is there any possible to get Network response in Using JavaScript.
After POST Request need to get values of "Request Payload" which is in Network.

[image]

Comment: Protractor doesn't have this capability. You could try using some third party package that has it or maybe try using Puppeteer instead.

Comment: I agree that you could use Puppeteer. You could also get it from network logging via webdriver. I think you could get the headers from this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114793/get-http-requests-performance-logs-from-chromedriver-with-protractor/49123392#49123392